# Cant run JPad - NoClassDefFoundError javafx scene parent

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, jpad

I haven't been able to run JPad (http://jpad.io) due to the below exception message.
What version of Java do you suggest?

```
    $> java -jar jpad.jar
    Nov 05, 2016 3:22:39 PM com.timestored.docs.OpenDocumentsModel addDocument
    INFO: addDocument: new 1
    Nov 05, 2016 3:22:40 PM io.jpad.JPadLauncher launch
    INFO: Starting JPadLauncher  launch() ###################################
    Nov 05, 2016 3:22:40 PM io.jpad.JPadFrame <init>
    INFO: Starting JPadFrame Constructor
    Nov 05, 2016 3:22:42 PM com.timestored.misc.ErrorReporter$UncaughtErrorReporter uncaughtException
    WARNING: uncaught error
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1321)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1296)
        at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(SwingUtilities.java:1348)
        at io.jpad.JPadLauncher.main(JPadLauncher.java:81)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/scene/Parent
        at io.jpad.JPadFrame.<init>(JPadFrame.java:177)
        at io.jpad.JPadLauncher.launch(JPadLauncher.java:110)
        at io.jpad.JPadLauncher.access$200(JPadLauncher.java:31)
        at io.jpad.JPadLauncher$2.run(JPadLauncher.java:83)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:301)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.scene.Parent
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 18 more
```

(I'm seeding this question as most noob posters of jpad don't have the 1500 rep for creating a tag)

Comment: Assuming you are the author of this tool: rather than seeding a tag and question here, why not make it abundantly clear on your website what version of Java is required? On an unrelated side note: auto-downloading a jar file when I go to the download tab feels super malware-y. Just saying...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPad relies on javafx for displaying HTML results. Not all versions on the JVM, parcilarly OpenJDK ship with these libraries.

I'm running Arch Linux and I noticed how the stack trace mentioned not being able to find a method in a JFX class so I thought I'd take a chance and see if my repos had a JFX package in them and they did. I installed it and tried again and that seems to have done the trick.